# Makefile : No rule to make target (automatic variables)

Tags: makefile

I am having trouble with my makefile, i have been reading somme tutoriels on how to make a more re-usable makefile but i am facing this error, and i have been searching for a while now, especially on the GNU make manual and here.

Here is my makefile :

```
SRC_DIR=./src
BUILD_DIR=./build
OBJS= $(BUILD_DIR)/main.o $(BUILD_DIR)/hamming.o

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

I am having the error :

> **make:  No rule to make target `build/main.o', needed by`build/main'.  Stop.**

It seems to me that the objects in the variable OBJS are not associated with the %.o pattern rule, but i don't know why.

In my working directory there is : my makefile and the two directories 'src' and 'build'.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll go out on a limb and guess that there is no `src/main.h`. If that's the case, you could fix things this way:

```
$(BUILD_DIR)/hamming.o: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o : $(SRC_DIR)/%.h

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@
```

**EDIT:**
Now I'm puzzled. Please try this (it is crude, but if it works we can refine it):

```
SRC_DIR=./src
BUILD_DIR=./build
OBJS= $(BUILD_DIR)/main.o $(BUILD_DIR)/hamming.o

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(SRC_DIR)/%.h
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/main.o: $(SRC_DIR)/main.c
    $(CC) -c $< $(CFLAGS) -o $@

$(BUILD_DIR)/main: $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS)
```

Comment: No there is no main.h.
In fact the error indicates that there is no rule for "main.o", so i tried to put $(BUILD_DIR)/main.o: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o but it does not make it. Thank you anyway.

Comment: Of course `$(BUILD_DIR)/main.o: $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o` won't work. *Try what I posted.*

Comment: The error message is probably confusing you: the implicit rule may have been matched and subsequently rejected (at step 5 in http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rule-Search); you should be able to determine this by looking at the output of `make -d`.

Comment: I got this doing "make-d" : http://pastebin.com/T5Li5rzs, i really don't know how to analyze this !

Comment: Pardon me if this is a stupid question but is there a `src/main.c`?

Comment: Yes there is.Also your line does work but only do the hamming.o file.
If i put the lines $(BUILD_DIR)/main: $(OBJS) ... $(CC) -o $@ $^ $(CFLAGS), i got the error message again.

Comment: Now it works perfectly.
So then i tried to do OBJS= $(BUILD_DIR)/hamming.o $(BUILD_DIR)/main.o so that the file hamming.o is done first, the hamming.o file is compiled but then i got the same error message with the main.o file. I guess that's because there is indeed no main.h, the dependencies are not satisfied (  $(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: $(SRC_DIR)/%.c $(SRC_DIR)/%.h  
) and so main.o is not made. So i created a main.h file, and now my original makefile works perfectly !
@Beta : You were exactly right, i guess, by pointing out that there were no src/main.h file, thank you !

Comment: @Laurant, this is very strange. The order of elements in `OBJS` should not matter. If you like we can investigate further, and write a cleaner makefile.

Comment: Well i think that the order does matter because the output indicates that main.o is done, then hamming.o and then the main file. Though maybe i am missing something. 

So the first .o in OBJS is the first to be done.

In fact, instead of $(BUILD_DIR)/main: $(OBJS) , i can write (i think) $(BUILD_DIR)/main: main.o hamming.o, and main.o is the first prerequisites.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a little documentation I put together for [NMake](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UsingNmake) a while back I hope it helps.  Are you sure there are only tabs before the commands.  You can't have spaces that is the number one error I have seen in the past.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I just checked and there is only one tab before every commands.